# difference between $query>num_rows() and $this->db->count_all_results() in CodeIgniter & which one is recommended

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a scenario I need to know the count of recordset a query will return, which in codeigniter can be done by `$query->num_rows()` or `$this->db->count_all_results()`. Which one is better and what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With `num_rows()` you first perform the query, and then you can check how many rows you got. `count_all_results()` on the other hand only gives you the number of rows your query would produce, but doesn't give you the actual resultset.

```
// num rows example
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('whatever');
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$num = $query->num_rows();
// here you can do something with $query

// count all example
$this->db->where('whatever');
$num = $this->db->count_all_results('table');
// here you only have $num, no $query
```

Comment: right, I guess I will use `count_all_results`, I need count in pagination, thanks a ton :)

Comment: `count_all_results` is far better if you are looking from optimization point of view.

Answer (score 5):

`$this->db->count_all_results` is part of an [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) query (preparing the query, to only return the number, not the actual results).

`$query->num_rows()` is performed on a [resultset object](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) (after returning results from the DB).

Comment: so to me it seems better to use `if($this->db->count_all_results()>0{//do stuff}` ?

Comment: If all you care about is the number of results found, then yes

Answer (score 3):

We can also use

```
return $this->db->count_all('table_name');
```

or

```
$this->db->from('table_name');
return $this->db->count_all_result();
```

or

```
return $this->db->count_all_result('table_name');
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->query('select * from tab');  
return $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Which one is better and what is the difference between these two` Its almost imposibble to me, someone just want to get the number of records without re-touching or perform another query which involved same resource. Furthermore, the memory used by these two function is in same way after all, since with `count_all_result` you still performing `get` (in CI AR terms), so i recomend you using the other one (or use count() instead) which gave you reusability benefits.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to count total number of records that the query will return.
First this

```
$query = $this->db->query('select blah blah');  
return $query->num_rows();
```

This will return number of rows the query brought.

Second

```
return $this->db->count_all_results('select blah blah');
```

Simply count_all_results will require to run the query again.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of results

```
$this->db->count_all_results('table name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply as bellow;

```
$this->db->get('table_name')->num_rows();
```

This will get number of rows/records. however you can use search parameters as well;

```
$this->db->select('col1','col2')->where('col'=>'crieterion')->get('table_name')->num_rows();
```

However, it should be noted that you will see bad bad errors if applying as below;

```
$this->db->get('table_name')->result()->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select count(*) as row from login WHERE firstname = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    print_r($query);exit;
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
```