# MySql Count not Accurate. Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently using Codeigniter. As shown below, a query looks up for the count of rows and then sent it to the view. However, the view does not shows the actual count. The actual count on DB (InnoDB) is 1001 but displays up to 1000 on my view. Any ideas?

```
    Model:
    public function check_source_email($location){
    $query="SELECT COUNT(*) as row_count FROM feedback WHERE location = '$location' AND source_lead = 'Email' ";
    $count=$this->db->query($query)->result();
    return $count[0]->row_count;
} 

    Controller:
    $data['email'] = $this->Stats->check_source_email($location); 

    View:
    <strong>Email Listing</strong><span class="pull-right"><?php echo $email; ?></span>
```

Comment: You mean that if you run the query via command line interface, you get 1001 but if you run through php/codeigniter you get 1000?

Comment: That's right. I do not know why. I did not have any 'LIMIT TO' at all.I know there are some limitations using InnoDB but I am not sure to what extend.

Comment: Have you tried doing a select on a field and returning the num_rows()? Just to see if it makes a difference? Like `SELECT `id` FROM `feedback``...

Comment: Are you sure what are you putting in phpmyadmin and the query in CI are identical?Maybe CI does some filtering for weird characters.Or just get the extra row and see whats different about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `num_rows`:

```
public function check_source_email($location){

   $query = $this->db->get_where('feedback',array('location'=>$location,'source_lead'=>'Email'));
   return $query->num_rows();

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this still select all the data from feedback? Is it basically `$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM feedback'); count($results); `That's terribly inefficient. [I think you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7037000/46675) `count_all_results()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try and do things the codeigniter way, if you are working with codeigniter:

```
public function check_source_email($location) {
  return $this->db
    ->where('location', $location)
    ->where('source_lead', 'Email')
    ->count_all_results('feedback');
}
```

That theoretically should return the correct result, although I'm not sure why your original didn't, but maybe this will fix it.