# Appropriate use of count_all_results()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So lets say that I have a data base called users, and for every user, there is an ID, OS_type, and LastName field. I would like to look through the data base and count the number of users that have a specific OS_type (lets use iOS for the example).

Would count_all_results() be the correct functions to use in this instance, or is there a more appropriate function in the database library?

```
$read_db = $this->load->database('read', TRUE);
$read_db->where(array('iOS' => $OS_type));
$read_db->from('users');
$count = $read_db->count_all_results();
```

is this the correct use of the function?

Comment: If you dont want to use any of the information for that particular request, then yes. If however you need to also use the data, then use `num_rows()`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036950/difference-between-querynum-rows-and-this-db-count-all-results-in-codei

Comment: This is best way instead of use num_rows() if you need only the counts

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `num_rows()` for count number of rows

```
$read_db->num_rows();
```

OR

```
$count = count($read_db->all);
```

Also you use write way to count the number of rows in a particular Active Record query by using `count_all_results()`

Comment: is this what you're proposing?                                                            $read_db = $this->load->database('read', TRUE);
$read_db->where(array('iOS' => $OS_type));
$read_db->from('users');
$count = count($read_db->all);

Comment: all method give you the number of rows in your query result

Comment: also what you want to count  and what problem you face

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand what your comments are referring to.

Comment: better you use `num_rows()` to get number of rows in your query

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this
`$read_db->num_rows();` it is useful