# Codeigniter Login and Logout session if not function right

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

My login and logout session is not function right in if, I don't know what to do it always caught on else than in if code. Even though the username and password that i input is the same as the one on the database

**Controller: Login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
        $this->load->model("Member_model");
    }

    public function loginMember() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('front/login');

        } else {

            //enter username and password
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $this->load->model('Member_model');
            $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password);

            if ($member > 0) {

                $data_session = array(
                    'nama' => $member->username,                
                    'logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);

                //redirect
                redirect('Member/profile');

            } else {

                print_r('User doesnt exist');

            }
        }
    }


    //logging out of a user
    public function logoutMember() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Member/Login');
    }
}
```

**Model:Member_model.php**

```
 public function checkLogin($username, $password) {

        $this->db->select('password');
        $this->db->from('member');
        $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password'=> $password));
        $hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');

        return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);

        if ($hash->num_rows()>0) {
            return $hash->row(); 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
   private function hash_password() {

    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   
}


private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash) {

    return password_verify($password, $hash);   
}
```

**View:Home.php**

```
<li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <?php echo $this->session->userdata("nama");?>
                                    Member<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('checkout')?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/shopping-cart.png')?>" style="height:15px;width:15px;"> Checkout</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('login/logoutMember')?>">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

I don't know what to do, the if($member) on the loginMember code in Login Controller is not working and always get to else every time I input data. But when I comment the if($member) like this:

```
         $this->load->model('Member_model');
            $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password);

            $_SESSION['logged_in']   = true;
            $_SESSION['username']    = $member->username;

            redirect('Member/profile');

//            if ($member > 0) {
//                
//                $data_session = array(
//                    'nama' => $member->username,                
//                    'logged_in' => true
//                );
//                $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
//                
//                //set session variables
////                $_SESSION['logged_in']   = true;
////                $_SESSION['username']    = $member->username;
//                
//                //redirect
//                redirect('Member/profile');
//                
//            } else {
//                
//                print_r('User doesnt exist');
//                
//            }
```

It's working perfectly, but I cannot use the session on view home when I called session username to show who is login that time. 
And I called the view in Controller Member, like this:

**Controller:Member.php**

```
public function profile() {
    if( $this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $data["slider"] = $this->Indexweb_model->getAll();
        return $this->load->view('front/home', $data);
    }
    redirect('Member/Login');
}
```

Comment: try in model if ($hash->num_rows() > 0) { return $result->result(); } else { return FALSE; } controller: if (!$member)

Comment: also in your controller you are checking for an integer but you are returning a row in your model. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036950/difference-between-querynum-rows-and-this-db-count-all-results-in-codei

Comment: Thank you it entered, but somehow the username still not read

Comment: In home I put this in navbar to show the name of the user that login, but it doesn't read <?php echo $this->session->userdata("nama");?>

Comment: if you're using  $member->username then you should be returning row_array() instead.

Comment: So i should using this "nama" => $username like that ?

Comment: change the 
return $hash->result();  to $hash->row_array(); or $hash->row();in your model

Comment: if ($hash->num_rows() > 0) { 
            return  $hash->row_array();

Comment: Like that? but it the username still not show up

Comment: $data_session = array(
                   'username' => $member->username,                
                    'logged_in' => true
               );
              $this->session->set_userdata($data_session); then use it as $this->session->username;

Comment: 'username' => $member->username became like this 'username' =>$this->session->username; or I need to code it bellow  $this->session->set_userdata($data_session)

Comment: Oh you mena in the home... I already change it like this <?php echo $this->session->username;?> but it the username still not come out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182473/discussion-between-yuukka-limson-and-kuroda-ayumu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in model

```
if ($hash->num_rows() > 0) { 
    return $hash->row(); 
} else { 
    return FALSE; 
}
```

controller:

```
if (!$member)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your index method of your controller:

```
public function index(){
        if( $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
          return redirect('Dashboard');
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
```

Comment: I put code like this for displaying the home...  public function profile() {

        if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== true) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Please login first to view");
            redirect('Member/Login');
        } else{
            $data["slider"] = $this->Indexweb_model->getAll();
            $this->load->view('front/home', $data);
        }
    }